# RedirectAttributes giving IllegalStateException in Spring 3.1

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm want to use [RedirectAttibutes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/index.html) property that has come up in Spring 3.1, I have the following handler method for post in my controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String register(@ModelAttribute("admin") Admin admin, BindingResult bindingResult, SessionStatus sessionStatus, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    redirectAttributes.addAttribute("admin", admin);
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return REGISTRATION_VIEW;

    }
    sessionStatus.setComplete();
    return "redirect:list";
}
```

But when I submit the form I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Argument [RedirectAttributes] is of type Model or Map but is not assignable from the actual model. You may need to switch newer MVC infrastructure classes to use this argument.
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveHandlerArguments(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:322)
```

I have come across a few gotcha's with redirectAttributes that you cannot use ModelAndView as the return type. So I returned just the string view.

Can anyone pl. tell me where I'm going wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Spring 3.1 introduced new version of Spring MVC backend implementation (`RequestMappingHandlerMapping`/`RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`) to replace the old one (`DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping`/`AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter`).

Some new features of Spring MVC 3.1, such as `RedirectAttributes`, are only supported by the new implementation.

If you use `<mvc:annotation-driven>` or `@EnableWebMvc` to enable Spring MVC, new implementation should be enabled by default. However, if you declare `HandlerMapping` and/or `HandlerAdapter` manually or use the default ones, you need to switch to the new implementation explicitly (for example, by switching to `<mvc:annotation-driven>`, if it doesn't break your configuration).

Comment: @EnableWebMvc for the controller solved the problem.  Where should be  "mvc:annotation-driven"  added?